# Hosting asp.core: how to replace obsolete RazorViewEngineOptions.CompilationCallback with AddApplicationPart?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

RazorViewEngineOptions.CompilationCallback become obsolete...

[image]

... when [detailed information provided by MS](https://aka.ms/AA1x4gg) recommends to configure assemblies with `ApplicationPartManager.AddApplicationPart` instead of CompilationCallback:

> Apps using these APIs to add assembly references to the compilation
>   context for runtime compilation should instead use
>   ApplicationPartManager.AddApplicationPart to add application parts for
>   each assembly reference

But `AddApplicationPart` can be applied only to IMvcBuilder when to start asp core in own process we use `WebHostBuilder` (which doesn't derive from IMvcBuilder)

```
var hostBuilder = new WebHostBuilder()
    // contains obsolete code
    //.ConfigureServices(TestManager.InitializeServices) 
    .AddApplicationPart(..); // compilation error, impossible to apply, IMvcBuilder expected !
```

How `AddApplicationPart` should be called? Where to get the `IMvcBuilder` ?

Previously used code (collects assemblies for asp server) that should be replaced with `AddApplicationPart`:

```
public static void InitializeServices(IServiceCollection services){
  services.Configure((RazorViewEngineOptions options) =>
  {
     var previous = options.CompilationCallback;
     options.CompilationCallback = (context) =>
     {
        previous?.Invoke(context);

        var assembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
        var assemblies = assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies().Select(x => MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Assembly.Load(x).Location))
                .ToList();
        assemblies.Add(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName("mscorlib")).Location));
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I use the

```
 services.AddMvc()
            .ConfigureApplicationPartManager(context =>
            {
                var startupAssembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
                var assemblies = startupAssembly.GetReferencedAssemblies().Select(Assembly.Load).ToList();
                assemblies.Add(Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName("netstandard")));
                assemblies.Add(Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName("mscorlib")));
                assemblies.Add(Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName("System.Private.Corelib")));
                assemblies.Add(Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName("System")));
                assemblies.Add(Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName("System.IO")));
                assemblies.Add(Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName("System.Linq")));
                assemblies.Add(Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName("System.Threading.Tasks")));
                assemblies.Add(Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName("System.Runtime")));
                assemblies.Add(Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName("System.Dynamic.Runtime")));
                assemblies.Add(Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime")));
                assemblies.Add(Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc")));
                assemblies.Add(Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor")));
                assemblies.Add(Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor")));
                assemblies.Add(Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.Abstractions")));
                assemblies.Add(Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName("System.Text.Encodings.Web")));
                foreach (var assembly in assemblies)
                {
                    context.ApplicationParts.Add(new AssemblyPart(assembly));
                }
            })
```

to replace the Compilationcallback
and it work, able to loal the assembies

Answer (score 0):

You can interact with the ApplicationPartManager in Startup when you configure MVC.

IMvcBuilder can be used when calling `AddMvc()`.

`services.AddMvc()
    .ConfigureApplicationPartManager(_ => _....)`

Comment: Yes I understand it, but  till now there were no need to intervent into the Startup from the code that configure hosting. When it seems like right now I should somehow pass parameters to the `Startup.ConfigureServices` if I need to support two hostings with different strategies to search for assemblies... Isn't it?